# Eclipslink - Unknown entity type

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, named-query

I am using some entities generated by Netbeans. After generation I tested them and they were working fine.  So then I had to move to my next step and combine those with my JAXB  objects. After combining with the JAXB objects I am able to unmarshall my XML stream with no problem. But when I try to use any of those classes for anything entity related I get some errors.

I am back at the testing phase again now and here is what I have. I have a test class just running from a simple main method. The same setup I used to test the entities originally.  Below you will see that test class, the Classes entity, The entity causing the issues JoinAssetToSku and the error. I have left out the majority of the setters and getters of the entities.  Does anyone know what is wrong with this JoinAssetToSku.findByTs query. I do not understand how it causes that error, it is not self aware!?

The code to do the testing:

```
public void testClassEntity(){
        testClass = new Classes(1);
        testClass.setClassId("12");
        testClass.setDescription("The First Class");
        testClass.setTs(new java.sql.Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
        ClassesJpaController cc = new ClassesJpaController();
            try {
                cc.create(testClass);
            } catch (PreexistingEntityException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(EntityTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(EntityTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
    }
```

The Classes class:

```
package entitiesjaxb.cmic.ajrs.com;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Classes", propOrder = {
    "pkId",
    "classId",
    "description",
    "ts"
})

@Entity
@Table(name = "classes")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Classes.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Classes c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Classes.findByPkId", query = "SELECT c FROM Classes c WHERE c.pkId = :pkId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Classes.findByClassId", query = "SELECT c FROM Classes c WHERE c.classId = :classId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Classes.findByDescription", query = "SELECT c FROM Classes c WHERE c.description = :description"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Classes.findByTs", query = "SELECT c FROM Classes c WHERE c.ts = :ts")})
public class Classes implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "pk_id")
    private Integer pkId;
    @Column(name = "class_id")
    @XmlElement(name = "ClassID")
    private String classId;
    @Column(name = "description")
    @XmlElement(name = "Description")
    private String description;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ts")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    private Date ts;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "classes", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @XmlTransient
    private Collection<Categories> categoriesCollection;

    public Classes() {
    }

    public Classes(Integer pkId) {
        this.pkId = pkId;
    }

    public Classes(Integer pkId, Date ts) {
        this.pkId = pkId;
        this.ts = ts;
    }
```

The class causing the error:

```
package entitiesjaxb.cmic.ajrs.com;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "JoinAssetToSKU", propOrder = {
    "pkId",
    "assetData",
    "skuBasic",
    "ts"
})

@Entity
@Table(name = "join_asset_to_sku")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "JoinAssetToSku.findAll", query = "SELECT j FROM JoinAssetToSku j"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "JoinAssetToSku.findByPkId", query = "SELECT j FROM JoinAssetToSku j WHERE j.pkId = :pkId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "JoinAssetToSku.findByTs", query = "SELECT j FROM JoinAssetToSku j WHERE j.ts = :ts")})
public class JoinAssetToSKU implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "pk_id")
    private Integer pkId;
    @Column(name = "ts")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    private Date ts;
    @JoinColumn(name = "pk_sku", referencedColumnName = "pk_id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private SKUBasic skuBasic;
    @JoinColumn(name = "pk_asset", referencedColumnName = "pk_id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private AssetData assetData;

    public JoinAssetToSKU() {
    }

    public JoinAssetToSKU(Integer pkId) {
        this.pkId = pkId;
    }

    public Integer getPkId() {
        return pkId;
    }

    public void setPkId(Integer pkId) {
        this.pkId = pkId;
    }
```

The error I am getting.

```
[EL Info]: 2011-04-15 08:26:58.223--ServerSession(2128911821)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.2.v20100323-r6872
[EL Severe]: 2011-04-15 08:26:58.525--ServerSession(2128911821)--Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-8034] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.2.v20100323-r6872): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Error compiling the query [JoinAssetToSku.findByTs: SELECT j FROM JoinAssetToSku j WHERE j.ts = :ts]. Unknown entity type [JoinAssetToSku].
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException.entityTypeNotFound(JPQLException.java:483)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.ParseTreeContext.classForSchemaName(ParseTreeContext.java:138)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.SelectNode.getClassOfFirstVariable(SelectNode.java:327)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.SelectNode.getReferenceClass(SelectNode.java:316)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.ParseTree.getReferenceClass(ParseTree.java:439)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.ParseTree.adjustReferenceClassForQuery(ParseTree.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.JPQLParseTree.populateReadQueryInternal(JPQLParseTree.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.JPQLParseTree.populateQuery(JPQLParseTree.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:202)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.JPAQuery.processJPQLQuery(JPAQuery.java:106)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.JPAQuery.prepare(JPAQuery.java:90)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:464)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:430)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.processJPAQueries(AbstractSession.java:1747)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:409)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.postConnectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:671)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:228)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:369)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getServerSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:207)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:195)
        at controllers.cmic.ajrs.com.ClassesJpaController.getEntityManager(ClassesJpaController.java:33)
        at controllers.cmic.ajrs.com.ClassesJpaController.create(ClassesJpaController.java:42)
        at cmicpojo.EntityTest.testClassEntity(EntityTest.java:33)
        at cmicpojo.Main.main(Main.java:45)

[EL Info]: 2011-04-15 08:26:58.545--ServerSession(2128911821)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.2.v20100323-r6872
Apr 15, 2011 8:26:58 AM cmicpojo.EntityTest testClassEntity
SEVERE: null
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-7092] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.2.v20100323-r6872): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot add a query whose types conflict with an existing query. Query To Be Added: [ReadAllQuery(name="KeyFeatures.findByBasicDescription" referenceClass=KeyFeatures jpql="SELECT k FROM KeyFeatures k WHERE k.basicDescription = :basicDescription")] is named: [KeyFeatures.findByBasicDescription] with arguments [[class java.lang.String]].The existing conflicting query: [ReadAllQuery(name="KeyFeatures.findByBasicDescription" referenceClass=KeyFeatures jpql="SELECT k FROM KeyFeatures k WHERE k.basicDescription = :basicDescription")] is named: [KeyFeatures.findByBasicDescription] with arguments: [[class java.lang.String]].
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.existingQueryTypeConflict(ValidationException.java:895)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.addQuery(AbstractSession.java:388)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.addQuery(AbstractSession.java:360)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.processJPAQueries(AbstractSession.java:1749)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:409)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.postConnectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:671)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.login(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:633)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:195)
        at controllers.cmic.ajrs.com.ClassesJpaController.getEntityManager(ClassesJpaController.java:33)
        at controllers.cmic.ajrs.com.ClassesJpaController.findClasses(ClassesJpaController.java:174)
        at controllers.cmic.ajrs.com.ClassesJpaController.create(ClassesJpaController.java:62)
        at cmicpojo.EntityTest.testClassEntity(EntityTest.java:33)
        at cmicpojo.Main.main(Main.java:45)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an error on my part, Combining the generated entities and generated JAXB classes led me to some classes named improperly.

The class name should be JoinAssetToSku to match the named query. Or I could leave the class name as JoinAssetToSKU and change the named query.

I chose to change the class name.